# Why doesn't this trigger work?

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

There are no errors - it just doesn't update the Asset__c field on the Asset's Account. All I can think is that I'm not initializing the Account correctly, but I can't see where the problem is. Any ideas?

```
Trigger UpdateAssetLookup on Asset(Before Insert)
{
    Set<Id> AccountIds = New Set<Id>();

    For(Asset Ass : Trigger.New)
    {
        AccountIds.Add(Ass.AccountId);
    }

    List<Account> AccountList = [Select Id,Asset__c from Account where id =: AccountIds];

    For(Asset AT : Trigger.New)
    {    
        For(Account ACC : AccountList)


                IF(AT.Id != NULL)
                {
                    ACC.Asset__c = AT.Id ;
                }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't working because the `Asset` Id field is null in the `before insert` context.

Records do not have Ids until `after insert`.

Beyond that, you're updating an `Account` record in your `Asset` trigger, but you aren't performing a DML update for those `Accounts`.

You can only avoid DML in triggers in `before` contexts on the same SObject (so in your `Asset` trigger, you can only avoid DML for the `Asset` records that caused the trigger to fire).

If you need to update other SObjects (like `Account`), Salesforce recommends using an `after` trigger.

**+edit:**

After taking a third look at your trigger, I think there's still more work that you need to do. Right now, you're updating the `Asset__c` field of each `Account` that you queried multiple times (meaning all of the `Accounts` you queried will have `Asset__c` set to whichever `Asset` record happens to be the last on in `Trigger.new`).

I doubt that's what you intend to have happen. You could fix things (and get rid of your nested loop) by putting the results of your `Account` query into a map (instead of a list), but you could completely avoid both the nested loop and your query for `Accounts`.

You could do this by using the following pattern (which you'll need to adjust to your particular situation).

```java
// Declare a list to hold records that we want to update
List<OtherObject__c> myOtherObjectsToUpdate = new List<OtherObject__c>();
for(MyObject__c myObj :Trigger.new){
    // Each SObject has a constructor that allows you to specify name-value pairs
    //   for fields.
    // You can use this to set the Id field (which is otherwise read-only).
    // Doing so allows you to update a record without the need to query for it first.
    myOtherObjectsToUpdate.add(new OtherObject__c(
        Id = myObj.OtherObject__c,        // just like all other method calls, name = value pairs are separated by commas in the constructor
        someLookupField__c = myObject.Id  // you can also set other writable fields in the constructor
    ));
}

update myOtherObjectsToUpdate;
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I did try it with an after insert context too, with no change in result. It must be that I need a DML then.

Comment: @ESil Since you're trying to update an `Account, yes, you do. I took a third look through your question/code and have edited my answer to include a few more suggestions.

Comment: Playing with this new pattern, I've run into a `Invalid initial expression type` error for the part where I set the new value of the lookup field (Asset__c = Asset.Id) - which I'm guessing is a problem with Asset__c being a lookup field and Asset.Id being an Id field?

Comment: @ESil lookup fields do actually store Ids, so that shouldn't be the issue. Giving the full text of the error (verbatim) may help, but I think the issue is probably in the `for(MyObject__c myObj :Trigger.new)` part. `Trigger.new` is a `List<Asset>` in your case, so `MyObject__c` should be replaced with `Asset`.

Comment: That did the trick :)